# [C#]Displaying images from folder in asp.net with prettyphoto slider

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am using prettyphoto slider to display couple of images from folder in my website in asp.net my code to retrive images is :

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
      {
          string[] filePaths =      Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/prettyPhoto/images/fullscreen/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/prettyPhoto/images/fullscreen/" + fileName));
        }

    }

}
```

and in asp page i use this code to display image :

```
   <a href="prettyPhoto/images/fullscreen/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="You      can add caption to pictures.">
        <img src="prettyPhoto/images/fullscreen/1.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Red round shape" /></a>
```

i have alot of images to display how can i display all of it with one statement i try change the `src` of image to `<%# eval(files)%>` but i think i miss something

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like :

```
@foreach (ListItem item in files) {
    <a href="@item.value">@item.text
    <img src="@item.value"/></a>

}
```

But I don't think that `ListItem` is really suited for this use, maybe you should use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), our just a list of string (`List<string>`)